# How do I do a 301 redirect with Azure Wordpress running Nginx?

Tags: wordpress, nginx, azure-web-app-service, alpine-linux, azure-appservice

I need to redirect HTTP to HTTPS, and www to non-www, with the Azure AppService version of Wordpress.  This version uses the wordpress-alpine-php docker image, running nginx version 1.20.2.

I think I need to add a server block to nginx.conf, but I am not sure which version of this file it's using.  I see the file in these locations.

- /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
- /home/site/wwwroot/nginx.conf

I've tried both of them, but neither seems to work.  The one under etc doesn't seem to persist a container reload.  I do know about copying the correct version and then reloading nginx with a startup command, as described in this Microsoft [article](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/configure-nginx-for-php-8-linux-azure-app-service/ba-p/3069373).

Is nginx.conf the place to do this?

Which versions of the file is this using at runtime?

Is there a better way to do this with the azure app service?

Comment: Yes, we need to add the 301-redirection rule in the `nginx.config` file itself.

Comment: Use `nginx -t` to learn which config file is the start of your investigation.